# Libgdx Game Crashes on Android Phone

Tags: android, libgdx, runtime-error, game-engine

I have created a sample game that runs perfectly on desktop but crashes with following error on android phone.

```
**Unfortunately, My LibGDX Game has stopped.**
```

I have tested with two different phones and even the emulator but the error remains the same. Below are the project properties for Android version.

[image: Project Properties for Android Version]

LogCat is(With Error Filter):

```
04-03 21:55:41.582: E/Trace(20583): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-03 21:55:42.022: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Defaults/Video:MaxWidth] = 1920
04-03 21:55:42.022: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[DivXs/Video:MaxWidth] = 1920
04-03 21:55:42.022: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Rtsps/UserAgent:Default] = Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android(stagefright alternative)
04-03 21:55:42.022: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Https/Streaming:PowerSave] = true
04-03 21:55:42.022: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] PlayerManager.GetPlayerType = 3
04-03 21:55:42.042: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(224): failed to extract an album art
04-03 21:55:42.052: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Defaults/Video:MaxWidth] = 1920
04-03 21:55:42.052: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[DivXs/Video:MaxWidth] = 1920
04-03 21:55:42.052: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Rtsps/UserAgent:Default] = Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android(stagefright alternative)
04-03 21:55:42.052: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Https/Streaming:PowerSave] = true
04-03 21:55:42.052: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] PlayerManager.GetPlayerType = 3
04-03 21:55:42.073: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(224): failed to extract an album art
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 666
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: images/smountains.png
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:175)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create(Texture.java:159)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:122)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.shoayb.defendearth.view.WorldRenderer.loadTextures(WorldRenderer.java:77)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.shoayb.defendearth.view.WorldRenderer.<init>(WorldRenderer.java:67)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.shoayb.defendearth.screens.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:15)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:59)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.shoayb.defendearth.DefendEarth.create(DefendEarth.java:8)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:292)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: images/smountains.png (Internal)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:67)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:561)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.length(AndroidFileHandle.java:149)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:221)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    ... 13 more
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: images/smountains.png
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:65)
04-03 21:55:42.543: E/AndroidRuntime(20583):    ... 17 more
04-03 21:55:43.324: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Defaults/Video:MaxWidth] = 1920
04-03 21:55:43.324: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[DivXs/Video:MaxWidth] = 1920
04-03 21:55:43.324: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Rtsps/UserAgent:Default] = Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android(stagefright alternative)
04-03 21:55:43.324: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Https/Streaming:PowerSave] = true
04-03 21:55:43.324: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] PlayerManager.GetPlayerType = 3
04-03 21:55:43.354: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(224): failed to extract an album art
04-03 21:55:43.364: E/MessageUtils(12466): [LGE]isMmsMemoryAvailable/freeSpace:6233837568/threshold:2097152
04-03 21:55:43.404: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Defaults/Video:MaxWidth] = 1920
04-03 21:55:43.404: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[DivXs/Video:MaxWidth] = 1920
04-03 21:55:43.404: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Rtsps/UserAgent:Default] = Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android(stagefright alternative)
04-03 21:55:43.404: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] GetPlayerSetup[Https/Streaming:PowerSave] = true
04-03 21:55:43.404: E/MediaPlayerService(224): [MediaPlayerService getPlayerType:fd] PlayerManager.GetPlayerType = 3
04-03 21:55:43.434: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(224): failed to extract an album art
```

Comment: can you post a stack trace?

Comment: where is the file `images/smountains.png`?

Comment: Packaging "files" for an android app to access at runtime is a bit tricky.  You'll need to specify where you tried to put it, **and also post the code where you tell Libgdx to try to use it**.

Comment: Show the line loading `images/smountains.png` and show where the file is in your android project.

Comment: It is located in ./assets/images/ and the line to access is                      sMountainTexture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/smountains.png"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody:) Issue is solved. Actually the file name was

> "smountains.PNG"

and in main libgdx project I was using the syntax with

> `sMountainTexture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/smountains.png"));`

The difference in case "png" and "PNG" didn't matter in case of Desktop Project but was taken as error in Android Version. Thanks every body again for help.